# Continuity, density and Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, baire-category

Let $X$ be a [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space), and $(Y,d)$ a metric space.
Assume that $f_n :X \rightarrow Y$ are continuous functions that pointwise convergence to $f :X \rightarrow Y$.

a) Prove that $A=\{x\in X | f$  is  continuous on $x \}$ is dense in $X$.

b) Prove that if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ isn't countable.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://www.math.ucsd.edu/programs/undergraduate/1213_honors_presentations/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf for a)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm sorry, I couldn;t find it there...Which Thm is it?

Comment: 2.2 and its corollary 2.3. Note that $f$ is a Baire class 1 function by definition 2.1.

Comment: b) then follows easily from this as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I understood a). For b),$A$ isn't countable because it's dense in $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: Dense sets can be countable (e.g. the rationals). But a second category set in the reals cannot be.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Because if A second categroy set could be countable,we could see it as a union of countable singletons which makes it from the first category?

Comment: That's indeed a correct argument for that case.